# Finding $ \max_{x \in [2,4]} \left| 2 x \cos(2 x) - (x - 2)^{2} \right| $.

Tags: calculus, optimization, numerical-methods

This is a problem taken from Burden’s and Faires’ *Numerical Analysis*. Define $ f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} $ by
$$
\forall x \in \Bbb{R}: \quad
f(x) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} 2 x \cos(2 x) - (x - 2)^{2}.
$$
How can I rigorously prove, without sketching a graph, that $ \displaystyle \max_{x \in [2,4]} |f(x)| = |f(4)| $? The problem is trivial if one sketches a graph.

Comment: Hm, you need to show that $f(\xi)<4-8\cos(8)$ where $4 - 2\xi + 2\cos(2\xi) - 4\xi\sin(2\xi)=0, 2\le\xi\le 4$ ?

Comment: Can you show that $f$ is maximized on the interval at $\pi$? If so, then it's a matter of estimating its value there and at $4$.

Comment: @Dan: Unfortunately, it doesn’t appear that $ f|_{[2,4]} $ is maximized at $ \pi $. However, numerical methods do show that the maximum of $ f|_{[2,4]} $ occurs near there.